# How can I determine the home base of a German-flagged aircraft?

Tags: airport, germany

Is there any way (lookup on website, database etc. or other means) how to determine the home base of an aircraft, specifically for an aircraft registered in Germany.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no official registration of the main operating base of aircraft in Germany.

What you could do is use FlightRadar24.com or similar aircraft tracking website and investigate the history of flights to determine the airport it is most frequently operating at.